# Can't we use oracle12c instead of mysql in node.js

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I have used Oracle 12c instead of mysql.
but I am getting "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306"
how to resolve this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb). Here's a [quick start video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQtRwTOwisI) you can check out too.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle’s network protocol is quite different from MySQL’s, and you can’t use a MySQL client library to connect to an Oracle database. The error message you quote looks like it’s from a MySQL client, since it’s trying port 3306, which is the default port for MySQL. There are Oracle clients for node.js, but I’ve never used any of them and don’t know how good they are.